# Can I download a byte[] and save it in file and then read it and send to again?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, bluetooth

I want to download something from webservice using ASYNCTASK

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

and then handle the inputstream and cut some parts LV and pass it to another device via bluetooth. Is it possible with Async task to do it? Unless, there is anyway to store the data received by AsynTask and be able accessing to it after? Or saving it into file and read it after ? (I don't have really experience in Android)
If there is a solution or an example it would be great :)

Comment: Yes, please look at an `AsyncTask` example, you can download data with it.

Comment: @JaredBurrows thnx yeah the point is not downloading , the point is after that if i saved it in a file in byte[] and then read it and send or there is another solution that i can handle it with interface and store it to be able to call it in another class